# First call of Edittext.SelectAll() not working in Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to select the text of a Edittext when I click on it.

```
public EditText Stock { get; set; }

Stock.Click += (o, arg) => {
    Stock.SelectAll();
};
```

Stock.SelectAll() is called correctly when I click on Stock. But the first time after starting my App and Clicking the Text it will not be selected. Every Click on it thereafter will work as intended.

Comment: "But the first time after starting my App the Text will not be selected" do you want the text to be selected without a click?

Comment: When is this click listener attached?

Comment: in the constructor of my class right after I inflate the view

Comment: Could you show that part of your code? And also other placed (if any) where you're setting the click listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all text in `EditText` when it is focused/ clicked, you can simply set `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in your xml for `EditText`.

Or in code behind, you may set:

```
Stock.SetSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Or if you insist to select all text through an event, use `FocusChange` event instead of `Click` event, the first click is handled by focus related event, it will not be fired. For example：

```
Stock.FocusChange += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.HasFocus)
    {
        Stock.SelectAll();
        var a = Stock.SelectionStart;
        var b = Stock.SelectionEnd;
        var text = Stock.Text.Substring(a, b);
    }
};
```

Comment: the problem is that since it is the first edittext it is already focused this does not work.

Comment: @b.holz, really? I just tested the code, works fine for the first focused `EditText`.